# selected attribute < html:option > for non-English locale

Tags: jsp, struts-1, taglib

I am working with Struts and TLDs.

I have a code something like this:

```
<html:select property="endAMPM" styleClass="inputField">
<html:option value=""></html:option>
<html:option value="AM" bundle="calendar" key="default.time.am"></html:option>
<html:option value="PM" bundle="calendar" key="default.time.pm"></html:option>
</html:select>
```

For English locale, it is rendering value properly, but for other non-English locale it was not rendering the default vaue as pre selected.

so, i have modified the code like this:

```
<bean:define id="am4"><bean:message bundle="calendar" key="default.time.am"/></bean:define>
                <bean:define id="pm4"><bean:message bundle="calendar" key="default.time.pm"/></bean:define>
                <html:select property="endAMPM" styleClass="inputField">
                    <html:option value=""></html:option>
                    <html:option value="<%=am4%>" bundle="calendar" key="default.time.am"></html:option>
                    <html:option value="<%=pm4%>" bundle="calendar" key="default.time.pm"></html:option>
                </html:select>
```

Now, it is redering the selected value properly. But, when i am submitting the form, it is not passing correct value to the **ActionClass**.

> With AM and PM value it is working fine, but not rendering the selected value on UI.

From org.apache.struts.taglib.html :

> > if (this.selectTag().isMatched(this.value)) {
> >                     results.append(" selected=\"selected\"");
> >                 }

Is there any way of keeping the value as AM and PM and still render the selected value properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parsing error for French locale with SimpleDateFormat(string,locale)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467863/parsing-error-for-french-locale-with-simpledateformatstring-locale)

Comment: what does it meant actually

Comment: [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47467863/parsing-error-for-french-locale-with-simpledateformatstring-locale/47525022#47525022)